# How to calculate the highest word frequency in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have been working on this assignment for a Coursera Intro to Rails course. We have been tasked to write a program that calculates maximum word frequency in a text file. We have been instructed to create a method which:

1. Calculates the maximum number of times a single word appears in the given content and store in `highest_wf_count`.
2. Identify the words that were used the maximum number of times and store that in `highest_wf_words`.

When I run the rspec tests that were given to us, one test is failing. I printed my output to see what the problem is but haven't been able to fix it.

Here is my code, the rspec test, and what I get:

```
class LineAnalyzer

  attr_accessor :highest_wf_count
  attr_accessor :highest_wf_words
  attr_accessor :content
  attr_accessor :line_number

  def initialize(content, line_number)
    @content = content
    @line_number = line_number
    @highest_wf_count = 0
    @highest_wf_words = highest_wf_words
    calculate_word_frequency
  end
  def calculate_word_frequency()
    @highest_wf_words = Hash.new(0)
    @content.split.each do |word|
      @highest_wf_words[word.downcase!] += 1
      if @highest_wf_words.has_key?(word)
        @highest_wf_words[word] += 1 
      else
        @highest_wf_words[word] = 1
      end
      @highest_wf_words.sort_by{|word, count| count}
      @highest_wf_count = @highest_wf_words.max_by {|word, count| count}
    end
  end
  def highest_wf_count()
    p @highest_wf_count
  end
end
```

This is the rspec code:

```
require 'rspec'

describe LineAnalyzer do
  subject(:lineAnalyzer) { LineAnalyzer.new("test", 1) }

  it "has accessor for highest_wf_count" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:highest_wf_count) 
  end 
  it "has accessor for highest_wf_words" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:highest_wf_words) 
  end
  it "has accessor for content" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:content) 
  end
  it "has accessor for line_number" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:line_number) 
  end
  it "has method calculate_word_frequency" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:calculate_word_frequency) 
  end
  context "attributes and values" do
  it "has attributes content and line_number" do
    is_expected.to have_attributes(content: "test", line_number: 1) 
  end
  it "content attribute should have value \"test\"" do
    expect(lineAnalyzer.content).to eq("test")
  end
  it "line_number attribute should have value 1" do
    expect(lineAnalyzer.line_number).to eq(1)
  end
end

  it "calls calculate_word_frequency when created" do
    expect_any_instance_of(LineAnalyzer).to receive(:calculate_word_frequency)
    LineAnalyzer.new("", 1) 
  end

  context "#calculate_word_frequency" do
    subject(:lineAnalyzer) { LineAnalyzer.new("This is a really really really cool cool you you you", 2) }

    it "highest_wf_count value is 3" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.highest_wf_count).to eq(3)
    end
    it "highest_wf_words will include \"really\" and \"you\"" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.highest_wf_words).to include 'really', 'you'
    end
    it "content attribute will have value \"This is a really really really cool cool you you you\"" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.content).to eq("This is a really really really cool cool you you you")
    end
    it "line_number attribute will have value 2" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.line_number).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the rspec output:

```
13 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/spec/line_analyzer_spec.rb:42 # LineAnalyzer#calculate_word_frequency highest_wf_count value is 3
```

My output:

```
#<LineAnalyzer:0x00007fc7f9018858 @content="This is a really really really cool cool you you you", @line_number=2, @highest_wf_count=[nil, 10], @highest_wf_words={"this"=>2, nil=>10, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "really"=>3, "cool"=>2, "you"=>3}>
```

1. Based on the test string, the word counts aren't correct.
2. "nil" is being included in the hash.
3. The hash is not being sorted by the value (count) like it should.

I tried several things to fix these problems and nothing has worked. I went through the lecture material again, but can't find anything that would help and the discussion boards are not often monitored for questions from students.

Comment: Please see "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the _minimal_ code that demonstrates the problem, the minimal input data to replicate it, and the expected output, in the question itself.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoriding to [Ruby documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/downcase%21):

> downcase!(*args) public
>
> Downcases the contents of str, returning nil if no changes were made.

Due to this unexpected behavior of `.downcase!` method, if the word is already all lowercase, you're incrementing occurrences of `nil` in this line:

```rb
@highest_wf_words[word.downcase!] += 1
```

Tests are also failing because `@highest_wf_words.max_by {|word, count| count}` returns an array containing the count and a word, while we want to get only the count.

A simplified `calculate_word_frequency` method passing the tests would look like this:

```rb
  def calculate_word_frequency()
    @highest_wf_words = Hash.new(0)

    @content.split.each do |word|
      # we don't have to check if the word existed before
      # because we set 0 as default value in @highest_wf_words hash

      # use .downcase instead of .downcase!
      @highest_wf_words[word.downcase] += 1

      # extract only the count, and then get the max
      @highest_wf_count = @highest_wf_words.map {|word, count| count}.max
    end
  end
```

Comment: "Due to this unexpected behavior of `.downcase!` method" – This is not really unexpected. It is how all similar methods behave as well. Also, it's a mutating method, why are you even expecting it to have a return value in the first case?

Answer (score 1):

**Nil**:

The nil is from `downcase!`

This modifies the String inplace and returns `nil` if nothing has changed.
If you say "this is weird", then you are right (IMHO).

```
# just use the non destructive variant
word.downcase
```

**Sorting**:

`sort_by` returns a new object (Hash, Array, ...) and does not modify the receiver of the method. You either need to re-assign or to use `sort_by!`

```
unsorted = [3, 1, 2]
sorted = unsorted.sort

p unsorted # => [3, 1, 2]
p sorted # => [1, 2, 3]

unsorted.sort!
p unsorted # => [1, 2, 3]
```

**Faulty word count**:

Once you corrected those two mistakes it should look better. Be aware, that the method does not return a single integer but a two-element array with the word and count, so it should look something like this: `["really", 6]`

**Simplifiying things:**

If you can use ruby 2.7, then there is the handy `Enumerable#tally` method!

```
%w(foo foo bar foo baz foo).tally
=> {"foo"=>4, "bar"=>1, "baz"=>1}
```

Example taken from
https://medium.com/@baweaver/ruby-2-7-enumerable-tally-a706a5fb11ea

Comment: "If you say "this is weird", then you are right (IMHO)." – I would rather say it is weird to even care about the return value of a mutating method at all.

Comment: It's weird in many regards, i think :-)

But i'd expect to return `self`, so it can be chained.